# Infer string literal type from string manipulation

Tags: typescript, template-literals

I've got a function that takes a string and creates an object mapping the four CRUD actions to "action" strings containing the argument:

```js
function createCrudActions(name: string) {
  const record = name.toUpperCase();

  return {
    create: `CREATE_${record}`,
    read: `READ_${record}`,
    update: `UPDATE_${record}`,
    delete: `DELETE_${record}`,
  };
}
```

Rather than have the type of each property in the returned object be `string`, I wanted to see if I could make them string literal types. I tried using template literal types to achieve this:

```js
type CrudActions = "create" | "read" | "update" | "delete";

type Actions<T extends string> = {
  [K in CrudActions]: `${Uppercase<K>}_${Uppercase<T>}`;
}

function createCrudActions<T extends string>(name: T) {
  const record = name.toUpperCase();

  return {
    create: `CREATE_${record}`,
    read: `READ_${record}`,
    update: `UPDATE_${record}`,
    delete: `DELETE_${record}`,
  };
}

const postActions: Actions<"post"> = createCrudActions("post");
```

But with this code, the TypeScript compiler doesn't see the function's return value as assignable to `Actions<T>`—the object's properties are still `string`. The error is:

> Type '{ create: string; read: string; update: string; delete: string;
> }' is not assignable to type 'Actions<"post">'.   Types of property
> 'create' are incompatible.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"CREATE_POST"'.

I tried using const assertions (`as const`) on each property value, as well as on the returned object itself, but the property types remain strings. Is there any way to do this without just casting the returned object (`as Actions<T>`)? If so, that would kind of defeat the purpose, so I'm hoping there's some way to make the compiler understand. But I think it might not be able to determine that the runtime `toUpperCase` call corresponds to the `Uppercase` transformation in the definition of `Actions<T>`.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgTgVwCYEEDGwCWB7AdgZygF4oAiNOCAQ2AlKgB8zKql6nSEwka7GykEADYRapANwAoSaEhR0WPPgA8AFSgQAHrVxJC+YHEy4A5gD5iUAN6SoUANoBpKMdiJUGHAQC6ALigABgAkVgCqYJBwaFT4EMqOZgC+APoh4ZHRsWpJAVKJ0gBmCLieeFAU1LTwyApeKupaOnpQBkamZgAUuFQAthD+qgCU1rblSsBQlGjYcEiW3X0AdMDY6RBwMDEQHYNSo5TACHC4I3Z2Fbz+ATAASgCiKKp3qVZTM0iJAQA0o3YsSFd7igACIvN6zT4-M5QLg8WhXUIABWBj2eIXBH2+vygghE8MCwLuABk7k8wRBphCsXZEnlpNMCBMwNgDLUlP42QRlKRmQZSBYSBcqu5OfgOjyWcBSLsgA)

Edit: Another approach that is close but not quite what I want:

```js
type CrudActions = "create" | "read" | "update" | "delete";

type ActionCreator = (s: string) => { [K in CrudActions]: `${Uppercase<K>}_${Uppercase<typeof s>}` };

const createCrudActions: ActionCreator = <T extends string>(name: T) => {
  const record = name.toUpperCase();

  return {
    create: `CREATE_${record}`,
    read: `READ_${record}`,
    update: `UPDATE_${record}`,
    delete: `DELETE_${record}`,
  };
}

const postActions = createCrudActions("post");
```

But in this case the return type for `createCrudActions("post") is:

```js
{
  create: `CREATE_${record}`;
  read: `READ_${record}`;
  update: `UPDATE_${record}`;
  delete: `DELETE_${record}`;
}
```

Whereas I'd like it to be:

```js
{
  create: `CREATE_POST`;
  read: `READ_POST`;
  update: `UPDATE_POST`;
  delete: `DELETE_POST`;
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgTgVwCYEEDGwCWB7AdgZygF4oAiNOCAQ2AlKgB8zKql6nSEwka7GykEADYRapANwAoSaEhR0WPPGrBscYlAAU+AFxR8wOJlwBzAJTEAfFADeUANoBpKMdiJUGHAQC6egAYAJDYAqmCQcGhU+BAAPI6WAL4A+kGh4ZHRMbIQ2ABm+ol+UAlSkmh4BlAUKhDwyApeuvKeSiyq6iQxACpQEAAetLhIhAZGppaauFQAthB6XRZE1jaSUFUVwFCU5XBIGlOzAHSqaRBwMFEQmmala5TACHC4tqtrVW1zUH4wAEoAoigun8UjZtmokAk-AAaV53ahIfz-FAAERBYN2kJhbygXB4tH8wQACsjAcCguiIdDYVBBCJ8V9kX8ADJ-IFoiA7SlY4pSBLScoETZgbAGBoVDTVXh1DyKAiaUjCgykG5AA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cajoled this to work with `as const` on all the properties *and* casting the `toUpperCase()` return value `as Uppercase<T>`; at that point, though, it's not that much better than `as Actions<T>`. Technically this validates the transformation as correct, but the code this protects is unlikely to change and the code that consumes it is equally well-protected from type errors.

```
function createCrudActions<T extends string>(name: T) {
  const record = name.toUpperCase() as Uppercase<T>;

  return {
    create: `CREATE_${record}` as const,
    read: `READ_${record}` as const,
    update: `UPDATE_${record}` as const,
    delete: `DELETE_${record}` as const,
  };
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgTgVwCYEEDGwCWB7AdgZygF4oAiNOCAQ2AlKgB8zKql6nSEwka7GykEADYRapANwAoSaEhR0WPPgA8AFSgQAHrVxJC+YHEy4A5gD5iUAN6SoUANoBpKMdiJUGHAQC6ALigABgAkVgCqYJBwaFT4EMqOZgC+APoh4ZHRsWpJAVKJ0gBmCLieeFAU1LTwyApeKupaOnpQBkamZgAUuFQAthD+qgCU1rblSsBQlGjYcEiW3X0AdMDY6RBwMDEQHcMxUGtRW9lSo5TACHC4I3Z2Fbz+ATAASgCiKKovqVZTM0iJAVA9tMCMAADSjOwsJAPV4oAAiXx+s3+gMIwIM4JuUC4PFoD1CAAU4e9PiEkX8AUDxpiboIRHjAnCXgAZF4fREQabIylo6mjRJ5aToiZgbAGWpKfwSgjKUiigykCwkO5VdzS-AdOVi4CkQbiIA)

Comment: YUou can use `as const` only once after `return { ... } as const ` or you can remove any type of assertions and [overload](https://tsplay.dev/mLLoAm) this function

Comment: @captain-yossarian Do you know why the overload is required in this case, as opposed to just specifying the return type of the function?

Comment: @Jimmy I have provided you an answer on your comment question but not on your original question.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you know why the overload is required in this case, as opposed to just specifying the return type of the function?

Consider this example:

```js
type CrudActions = "create" | "read" | "update" | "delete";

type Actions<T extends string> = {
  [K in CrudActions]: `${Uppercase<K>}_${Uppercase<T>}`;
}

function createCrudActions<T extends string>(name: T):Actions<T> {
  /**
   * toUpperCase returns string instead of Uppercase<T>,
   * hence `CREATE_${record}` is now `CREATE_${string}` whereas you
   * want it to be `CREATE_${Uppercase<T>}`
   */
  const record = name.toUpperCase();

  return {
    create: `CREATE_${record}`,
    read: `READ_${record}`,
    update: `UPDATE_${record}`,
    delete: `DELETE_${record}`,
  } as const; // error
}

const postActions = createCrudActions("post").create;
```

It is clear why we have an error here. Because `toUpperCase` returns `string` whereas we want to operate on `Uppercase<T>`.

But why overloading works in this case? Function overloading acts bivariantly, it means that it compiles if overdload is assignable to function type signature or vice versa. Of course, we loose type strictness but gain flexibility.

See this exmaple, without overloading:

```js
function createCrudActions<T extends string>(name: T) {

  const record = name.toUpperCase();

  const result = {
    create: `CREATE_${record}`,
    read: `READ_${record}`,
    update: `UPDATE_${record}`,
    delete: `DELETE_${record}`,
  } as const;

  return result
}

const result = createCrudActions("post");

type Check1<T extends string> = typeof result extends Actions<T> ? true : false

type Check2<T extends string> = Actions<T> extends typeof result ? true : false

type Result = [Check1<'post'>, Check2<'post'>]
```

`Result` is `[false, true]`. Since `Result` has at least one `true`, function overloading should work.

Version with overloading:

```js
type CrudActions = "create" | "read" | "update" | "delete";

type Actions<T extends string> = {
  [K in CrudActions]: `${Uppercase<K>}_${Uppercase<T>}`;
}

function createCrudActions<T extends string>(name: T): Actions<T>
function createCrudActions<T extends string>(name: T) {
  const record = name.toUpperCase();

  return {
    create: `CREATE_${record}`,
    read: `READ_${record}`,
    update: `UPDATE_${record}`,
    delete: `DELETE_${record}`,
  } as const;
}

const result = createCrudActions("post");
```

Try to add extra `underscore`  to `Actions` utility type:

```js
type Actions<T extends string> = {
  [K in CrudActions]: `_${Uppercase<K>}_${Uppercase<T>}`;
}
```

Now, overloading is not assignable to function type signature because non of the types are not assignable to each other.

However, you can move `upercasing` to a separate function. In this way you will create only a little piece of unsafe code whereas your main function will be `safe`. When I say `safe` I mean : `as much as TS allows it to be safe`.

```js
type CrudActions = "create" | "read" | "update" | "delete";

const uppercase = <T extends string>(str: T) => str.toUpperCase() as Uppercase<T>;

function createCrudActions<T extends string>(name: T) {
  const record = uppercase(name)

  return {
    create: `CREATE_${record}`,
    read: `READ_${record}`,
    update: `UPDATE_${record}`,
    delete: `DELETE_${record}`,
  } as const;
}

const result = createCrudActions("post").create
```

Now you don't even need `Actions` type because TS is able to infer all types on its own